# Disable query log in sphinx

Tags: logging, sphinx

Can somebody give me the answer how to disable 'query_log' in sphinx?

My server diskspace is overloaded with this query_log every time.

Answer (score 1):

Even better is to setup log rotation
http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/logrotate8.html

that way you have recent logs you can consult.

Otherwise look for the query_log entry in sphinx.conf
http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#conf-query-log

> **query_log**
>
> Query log file name. Optional, default is empty (do not log queries).

Answer (score 0):

a sample of log rotation is on the tips and tricks pagge

http://sphinxsearch.com/wiki/doku.php?id=tips_and_tricks